# Post request failing with python httplib2, works with curl

Tags: python, post, oauth, httplib2, fitbit

I'm trying to request access tokens from the fitbit API, but it keeps returning 401 Unauthorized status, even though I configure the request identical to a corresponding curl query - which succeeds. The error message returned says: `"errorType":"invalid_client","message":"Invalid authorization header format.` Is there some nuance of how httplib2 builds its requests that is throwing me off here?...

(Working) curl query:

```
curl    -X POST -i 
-H 'Authorization: Basic <LONG_CODE>'
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
-d "clientId=<CLIENT_ID>" 
-d "grant_type=authorization_code" 
-d "redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A5000%2Ffitbit-callback" 
-d "code=<AUTHORIZATION_GRANT_CODE>" 
https://api.fitbit.com/oauth2/token
```

Non-working python request (edited):

```
TOKEN_URL = 'https://api.fitbit.com'/oauth2/token'
CALLBACK_URI  = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/fitbit-callback'

auth_header = base64.b64encode(bytes(<CLIENT_ID> + ':' + <CLIENT_SECRET>, 'utf-8'))
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % auth_header,
    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }

params = {
    'client_id': <CLIENT_ID>,
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
    'redirect_uri': CALLBACK_URI,
    'code': <AUTHORIZATION_GRANT_CODE>
    }
urlparams = urlencode(params)

resp, content = h.request(TOKEN_URL, 
    'POST', 
    urlparams,
    headers)
```

Not evident from code:

- the `auth_header`-variable in python matches `<LONG_CODE>`

Terminal response after `python3 fitbit.py`:

```
send: b"POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: api.fitbit.com\r\nContent-Length: 153\r\nauthorization: Basic b'<LONG_CODE>'\r\ncontent-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nuser-agent: Python-httplib2/0.10.3 (gzip)\r\naccept-encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n\r\n"
send: b'client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A5000%2Ffitbit-callback&code=<AUTHORIZATION_GRANT_CODE>'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized\r\n'
header: Date header: Content-Type header: Transfer-Encoding header: Connection header: Cache-control header: WWW-Authenticate header: Content-Language header: Content-Encoding header: Vary header: X-Frame-Options header: Server header: CF-RAY
```

Running `print(content)`:

```
b'{"errors":[{"errorType":"invalid_client","message":"Invalid authorization header format. Visit https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/oauth2 for more information on the Fitbit Web API authorization process."}],"success":false}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is awkward. I didn't notice it before I directed the requests towards a request capture service that let me analyze them (like runscope), but I seem to simply have missed the `b'<LONG_CODE>'` formatting in the python example. This fixed it:

`auth_header.decode("utf-8")`

Maybe this question should be deleted, if it is unlikely to help anyone else...